# drag and drop an image on android / chrome

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, drag-and-drop, draggable

I'm trying to get dragging an image on android (chrome) to work, but when I, for example, try the demo from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop) I get the following

[image]

In words: Instead of let me drag the image around, chrome thinks I want to do something else with the image, like open it in a new tab or it reloads the page when I try to drag.

So, I've been playing with this, like wrapping the image in a `div` and make that div draggable,

```
<div draggable="true">
    <img src=".....png">
</div>
<div class="drop-zone" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7c0h6fpp/6/)

But cannot get it to work on chrome (v63.0.3239.111) on my android (v4.4.2; SM-T230 Build/KOT49H) device. So any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just check [browser compatibility list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransferItem#Browser_compatibility) and you can see that Chrome for Android does not support this HTML5 feature. If you want drag&drop on mobile, jQuery UI should handle it..

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing this out, because I though that it did work on android. (https://caniuse.com/#feat=dragndrop)